# Multiply constant to \widthof

Tags: width, resize, calc

I'm trying to compress some text using `\resizebox`.
When I use an absolute value, it works fine

```
\resizebox{2em}{\height}{AAAAA}
```

when I use a partial of e.g. `\textwidth` it also works fine

```
\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{\height}{AAAAA}
```

**but** using a partial of `\widthof` like above returns an error

```
\resizebox{0.8\widthof{AAAAA}}{\height}{AAAAA}
```

> See the calc package documentation for explanation. Type  H 
> for immediate help.  ...
> l.28 ...izebox{0.8\widthof{AAAAA}}{\height}{AAAAA}
> I expected to see one of: + - * / )

and when I add a star i get

```
\resizebox{0.8*\widthof{AAAAA}}{\height}{AAAAA}
```

> \calc@Acount
> l.28 ...zebox{0.8*\widthof{AAAAA}}{\height}{AAAAA}
> I can't carry out that multiplication or division, since the result is out of range

So how do I multipy a constant to `widthof` correctly?

---

<s>**Update**: `\resizebox{\widthof{AAAAA} * \real{0.8}}...` also does not work</s>

Comment: You should not use \resizebox with text. You'll get inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: @Bernard ok... what would be the best alternative?

Comment: I'd go to smaller font size such as \footnotesize.  This depends on the context and on what  you're aiming at, of course.

Comment: `\resizebox{\widthof{AAAAA}*\real{0.8}}{\height}{AAAAA}` **does** work.
In `calc` multiplication of a length with a number must be done with the number at the end.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum ok... now it works indeed... don't ask me why it didn't the first time i checked 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\resizebox{\widthof{AAAAA} * \real{0.8}}{\height}{AAAAA}` does the job